# Airbus' official language

Tags: airbus

I would like to know which language Airbus uses when they create the original version of their official documents.

So.. which language do they use? German or French?

Answer (score 12):

The official business language of Airbus is **English**. All official documents are written in English (and then possibly translated, if required).

This is what Fabrice Brégier (former COO of Airbus) said on the topic in 2014:

> “Airbus’s language is English. I’m not going to tell you that when there are two French people in my office we speak in English, but we systematically speak English, emails are in English," Bregier said.

<sup>(Airbus chief: ‘I no longer think like a Frenchman’, [thelocal.fr](https://www.thelocal.fr/20140320/france-needs-to-love-its-companies/))</sup>

This is also confirmed by the current Airbus Careers FAQ page:

> **Do I need to speak a foreign language to work at Airbus?**
>
> The business language at Airbus is English. Each job listing in the Job Market includes the specific language requirements for the position. Being able to speak French, Spanish or German is also an asset.

<sup>([airbus.com](https://www.airbus.com/en/careers/careers-faqs))</sup>

Comment: English is the universal language of aviation.  Few technical publications are translated into other languages (unless an airline wants to pay for it, which they won't).  Mechanics at airlines must learn enough english to read a maintenance manual, even in places like China.  For this reason tech pubs have used an English style standard called AECMA Simplified English since the late 80s.